# Get 3 words from the text

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write a regular expression to get three words from the text. Words are separated with one space. And I wrote the code that gives me not all sequences.
For example for text "one two three four five six" I got only two sequences: 1.one two three 2.four five six. But I want my regular expression to give me all sequences  so the output would be: 1.one two three 2.two three four 3.three four five. 4.four five six.
Can somebody tell me please what's wrong with my regular expression?
Here is my code:

```
   string input = "one two three four five six";
   string pattern = @"([a-zA-Z]+ ){2}[a-zA-Z]+";
   Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
   if (matches.Count > 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
       Console.WriteLine();
       foreach (Match match in matches)
           Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. For me, all sequences would be *one two three*, *two three four*, *three four five* and *four five six*

Comment: Yes, you are wright, I am sorry. I want to get all that sequences: 
one two three, two three four, three four five and four five six.
I've already edited my question

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with only one regex and one iteration.

Comment: But how then to do it with more than one regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your regular expression - it's just how regular expressions work. When you find a match, the search for the next match continues at the *end of the one you just found* - the width of the match is *consumed*.

So, how to fix this? One way is to make your match *not consume anything*. You can do this by placing your original pattern in a zero-width positive lookahead assertion:

```
string pattern = @"(?=([a-zA-Z]+ ){2}[a-zA-Z]+)";
added --->         ***                        *
```

`(?=pattern)` says "only match at this point if it's immediately followed by soemthing matching `pattern`" - but the content matching `pattern` isn't part of the overall match, so it isn't consumed.

If it's not part of the match, though, it doesn't appear in `match.Value` - so how do you get the value out? Simple - just add a capturing group around the original pattern (i.e. `(?=(pattern))`), and the captured group will appear in your results as normal.

```
string pattern = @"(?=(([a-zA-Z]+ ){2}[a-zA-Z]+))";
added --->            *                        *
```

So now, you can go through your `foreach` loop as before, but `match.Value` will be empty - your desired result is in `match.Groups[1].Value`.

But now you have another problem. Your results are

```
one two three
ne two three
e two three
two three four
wo three four
```

and so on. This is because your pattern matches *even when you start halfway through a word*.

How to fix this?

We add another zero-width assertion, this time a *negative lookbehind*: `(?<![a-zA-Z])`. Rather than saying "only match if this point is followed by the pattern", it says "*never* match if this point is *preceeded* by the pattern". Thus we'll never match at a point preceeded by a letter. `ne two three` isn't returned, for example, as it's preceeded by `o`.

```
string pattern = @"(?<![a-zA-Z])(?=(([a-zA-Z]+ ){2}[a-zA-Z]+))";
added --->         *************
```

With this pattern, you finally get your expected results.

Comment: @Yarik Glad to hear it; I hope you can take something away from this and use it in different situations in the future :)